# I can't find my app in the permissions list

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application for working with files, respectively, I request permission to access all files. However, in new versions of android, you need to find your application among others and click on toggle to give access.

When I open intent to request permission, my application is not in the list

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.quazzyapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PERMISSION_STORAGE = 101;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (!PremissionUtils.hasPermissions(MainActivity.this)) {
            PremissionUtils.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSION_STORAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

PremissionUtils.java

```
package com.example.quazzyapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.Settings;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class PremissionUtils {
    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void requestPermissions(Activity activity, int requestCode) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", activity.getPackageName())));
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                    new String[] { android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                    requestCode);
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.quazzyapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.quazzyapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

AndriodManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.QuazzyApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

There is a possibility that the problem is located locally on the tested smartphone, unfortunately I can't check on other devices

I created an intent to request permissions in a new project to exclude the influence of other pieces of code, but nothing happened and the problem remained

Comment: "When I open intent to request permission, my application is not in the list" -- the file that matters for this is your manifest. You may want to add that to your [mcve]. Also, please note that it is unlikely that your app will be approved for distribution on the Play Store (or perhaps elsewhere) given your request for this permission. You might wish to consider alternative approaches for building your app that can avoid that permission. Otherwise, be prepared to provide Google with a very good reason why it is impossible to implement your app without that permission.

Comment: Have you included the permission in AndroidManifest?

Comment: I added the manifest code, I'm sorry, I forgot about it

Comment: @CommonsWare - what permission do you recommend, for writing and reading files, perhaps in the application folder without accessing external files?

Comment: In the abstract, I recommend not using any permission. Instead, use the Storage Access Framework, such as `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`, to allow the user to choose what content you should work with.

Comment: @CommonsWare - thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION" />
```

That is not a permission string. It is an `Intent` action string. Replace that XML element with:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).